# How to obtain all direct parent-child relationships in a graph with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph with multiple levels, and I need to create a query that would extract all direct child-parent relationships in a table.

For example, if I have a graph like this:

[image]

I want as an output, the following table:

---

```
Parent             Child
```

---

```
1                    2
```

---

```
1                    3
```

---

```
2                    4
```

---

```
2                    5
```

---

```
3                    6
```

For now, I am extracting these relations separately in multiple MATCH queries, but I'm sure there is a better way out there. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what are your use cases? what is the query that you have that uses "multiple MATCH queries"? You will get an accurate answer if the question is complete.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
MATCH(parent)-->(child)
RETURN DISTINCT
    parent.id_of_node, child.id_of_node
ORDER BY
    parent.id_of_node, child.id_of_node
;
```

second answer is

```
/* collect id_of_node of target nodes by the condition you want */
MATCH path=(parent)-[*0..]->(child)
WHERE parent.name = 'X'
WITH NODES(path) as nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT node.id_of_node) as ids_of_node
/* using ids_of_node as a condition, get final answer */
MATCH(parent)-->(child)
WHERE parent.id_of_node IN ids_of_node OR child.id_of_node IN ids_of_node
RETURN DISTINCT
    parent.id_of_node , child.id_of_node 
ORDER BY
    parent.id_of_node , child.id_of_node 
;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! And what if there is a condition on one of the parent"s properties? For example, that parent.name = 'X'

If I try "MATCH (parent {name:"X"})-->(child)", it will return nodes 2 & 3, without displaying the rest of child-parent rels. Hope this makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from norihide.shimatani is also valid. As an another option, you can try below one with union all.

```
MATCH (parent {name:'x'})-->(child)
RETURN parent.number as parentNumber, child.number as childNumber 
UNION ALL
MATCH (parent {name:'x'})-->(child1)-->(child2)
RETURN child1.number as parentNumber, child2.number as childNumber
```